# Java Object init() and the Timer class

Tags: java, concurrency, constructor

I was just writing some code, and it occurred to me. I am creating a Timer object and scheduling a repeating task via `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`.

```
public class MyClass {
  ..
  public MyClass() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doStuffEachSecond();
        }
    }, (long)0, (long)1000);
    // more stuff
  }
```

Now, `doStuffEachSecond()` is an instance method on `MyClass`. Since my initial delay is **zero**,
and there is more stuff that goes on in the constructor after my Timer is set up, how do I know that the first invocation of my timer won't occur *before* object initialization is complete? Or might that potentially be the case (which would of course not be good)?

For now my solution is that my timer's setup *is* the final step of the constructor, but that seems iffy at best. Any wisdom regarding this issue?

Comment: Offtopic: You can just use `0L` and `1000L` instead of casting with `(long)`

Comment: Maybe you can try add a `trifle` delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something similar to what threads in Java do.  Have a constructor, then call a method like `start` to begin the timer.

Resolving race issues here seems a bit overkill when you can just construct the object then immediately begin timing.  If you have a Factory to create the objects this could be part of the construction process.

Comment: I think what you and Grezegorz have suggest sits best with me. I'd prefer to be 100% safe by kicking off the timer after object initialization has been completed, than starting it during construction which will "probably" be okay.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to insure that `MyClass` is fully initialized before the timer starts, you can do the initialization and the timer start in two steps:

```
final MyClass myMlass = new MyClass();
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      myclass.doStuffEachSecond();
  }
}, 0L, 1000L);
```

---

***Edit***

After thinking about it, putting the above in a static factory method would be by *far* the best solution:

```
public class MyClass {
  private MyClass() { /* do stuff */ }
  public static MyClass createNew() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.startRunning();
  }   
  private void startRunning() {
    new Timer(true).scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doStuffEachSecond();
        }   
    }, 0L, 1000L);
  }   
}
```

This does *everything* you want.  The only way to create a new `MyClass` is via its factory method, and whenever a new one is created its timer is started *after* it's initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I would **separate scheduling from object creation**. You are right that it smells.

```
public class MyClass {

  ...

  public MyClass() {
    ...
  }

  public static void start(final MyClass mc) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mc.doStuffEachSecond();
        }
    }, (long)0, (long)1000);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Do this instead: Call the method  in the class you are using the MyClass object. 


  public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
            // more stuff
          }
        private void startTimer(){
            Timer timer = new Timer(true);
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doStuffEachSecond();
                }
            }, (long)0, (long)1000);
        }

   public class usingClass{
          public static void main(String args[]){
               MyClass mc=new MyClass();
               mc.startTimer();
          }

   }
```